# Storing RSA public key into iOS keychain using kSecAttrAccessible

Tags: ios, objective-c, keychain

So I know that I can store a RSA key into the keychain using my following code:

```
+ (void)savePublicKeyToKeychain:(NSData *)key tag:(NSString *)tagString deleteExisting:(BOOL)deleteExisting {
    NSData *tag = [SecKeyWrapper getKeyTag:tagString];

    NSDictionary *saveDict = @{
            (__bridge id) kSecClass : (__bridge id) kSecClassKey,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyType : (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrApplicationTag : tag,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClass : (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
            (__bridge id) kSecValueData : key
    };
    [self saveKeyToKeychain:saveDict tag:tagString deleteExisting:deleteExisting];
}

+ (void)saveKeyToKeychain:(NSDictionary *)saveDict tag:(NSString *)tagString deleteExisting:(BOOL)deleteExisting {
    OSStatus sanityCheck = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) saveDict, NULL);
    if (sanityCheck != errSecSuccess) {
        if (sanityCheck == errSecDuplicateItem && deleteExisting) {
            // delete the duplicate and save again
            SecItemDelete((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) saveDict);
            sanityCheck = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef) saveDict, NULL);
        }
        if (sanityCheck != errSecSuccess) {
            NSLog(@"Problem saving the key to keychain, OSStatus == %d.", (int) sanityCheck);
        }
    }
    // remove from cache
    [keyCache removeObjectForKey:tagString];
}
```

This I can save and retrieve correctly. If I try to set the `kSecAttrAccessible` value on save:

```
+ (void)savePublicKeyToKeychain:(NSData *)key tag:(NSString *)tagString deleteExisting:(BOOL)deleteExisting {
    NSData *tag = [SecKeyWrapper getKeyTag:tagString];

    NSDictionary *saveDict = @{
            (__bridge id) kSecClass : (__bridge id) kSecClassKey,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyType : (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyTypeRSA,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrApplicationTag : tag,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClass : (__bridge id) kSecAttrKeyClassPublic,
            (__bridge id) kSecAttrAccessible: (__bridge id) kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly,
            (__bridge id) kSecValueData : key
    };
    [self saveKeyToKeychain:saveDict tag:tagString deleteExisting:deleteExisting];
}
```

and then trying to retrieve, I get junk. It's junk because when I retrieve it immediately after I save, the inserted value and the retrieved value are different.

Anyone have a code sample or know how to set the accessibility of the keychain item, specifically for an RSA key?

Comment: I had similar problem.  Turned out that I was missing kSecAttrKeyClassPublic attribute, even though in other calls (e.g. get a key reference) just application tag was enough. But for SecItemAdd every attribute is important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For public knowledge, it turns out that the attributes used to store the data to the keychain needs to be ***EXACTLY*** what is used to retrieve the data from the keychain. If you're missing one of the attributes, even though it seems like an attribute needed only for storing (like `kSecAttrAccessible`), you'll get the wrong data. You won't even get a `errSecItemNotFound`. It returns garbage.

Comment: That makes sense, that garbage you get is probably the data decrypted incorrectly since it was getting the incorrect accessible attribute.

Comment: @Joe: actually, it's the key bits that are garbage, not the data. If none of the attributes match, the method should return `errSecItemNotFound`, not pretend success with a bad key. There's nothing here that involves the data, just the storing and retrieving of the key. To me, a key should be added with all sets of attributes. It should then be retrieved with any attributes that match (like a search) rather than requiring ALL the attributes used on insertion. The current behavior encourages developers to store keys with the minimal number of attributes possible, so that a retrieval is easier.